# Cannot set text color of Send and Cancel buttons in the mail composer when presented from the UIActivityViewController in iOS10

Tags: objective-c, xcode, email, ios10, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am using the UIActivityViewController to share items in iOS10. When I tap on the Mail option, it pops up the mail composer, but the Cancel and Send buttons on the navigation bar and the navigation bar itself are blue, making it very difficult to read, so I want to change their color. The same thing with SMS sharing.
I tried this

```
[[[controller navigationController] navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

and this

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UINavigationBar class]]] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

and this

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

and this

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

but nothing works. I even tried to subclass `UIActivityViewController` but it's method `- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion` never called.
I don't know what to do next. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```